# Figure not showing in multi-file latex project

Tags: floats, input, include, multiple-files

I am trying to include a figure in a large document. It works fine directly. But when I call it in another file using \include or \input, the figure does not show. It is a simple code as below.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Economics.jpg}
\end{figure}

Comment: Without seeing a MWE, it will be hard to tell.  I don't suppose you have your other file in subdirectories?  `\includegraphics` needs to give the file location from the main tex file, not from the included file.

Comment: it should show or you should get an error in the log saying the file is not found. Also are you sure it is not showing or has it floated to later in the document?